# How can I manage the daily saving of tables in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently trying to program a Fitness App a a side project.

I am using Room to read and write a daily questionnaire that's asking you up to 3 times a day.

I am now currently having the problem that with my Method all 21 Questions are stacking in one Table called "Questionnaire" each time I enter my answers etc.

[image]

I have thought about exporting them as SQL Files each time to a Directory based on time and date to later visualize and analyze the data.

This Question might be a bit of too broadly asked but I am new to coding and would appreciate every idea someone has to manage this smartly.

Comment: Sounds like you just want another table that groups each day's answers together

Comment: Why is this not solved with date and type columns?

Comment: Yes, it's good that they are in one table. You can filter the table by what's in certain columns when you query it.